# Can I unlink my Windows (8-10) computer user profile from my hotmail account?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, user-profiles, hotmail

When I got my computer, Windows basically demanded that I put in my hotmail account information.  I have now upgraded to Windows 10.

I would like to know if it is possible to now unlink my Windows computer user profile from my MSN/Hotmail account?

If it is possible, then how do you do it?

Comment: Quick Google tells you how: http://www.howtogeek.com/230543/how-to-revert-your-windows-10-account-to-a-local-one-after-the-windows-store-hijacks-it/

Comment: You can create a local account in Windows 8, the fact you didn't, just means you missed the option.  How you create a local user has remained unchanged.  The only change between Windows 7 Windows 8 is really the OOBE (Out of Box Experience) on how you create the initial user.  It also is well documented on how you unlink your Microsoft Account.  What research have you performed on this subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In widows 10, its under **manage your account**.  There you can switch to a local user.  I have been running as a local user from the beginning.